# How to set color of palette in fusion chart?

Tags: html, fusioncharts

```
<chart palette='1' ...>
```

How to set color of palette in fusion chart?
 I want my own color("palette":"eef5fb") to set in fusion chart.

```
    var trendjson='{ "caption" : "","slantlabels": "1", "xaxisname": "Dates","yaxisname": "Count","palette":"eef5fb","set":[';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your own palette for data items by providing a list of hex colors:

`paletteColors='FF5904,0372AB,FF0000'`

For more details, please refer to “chart palettes” in the [FusionCharts Documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?AttDesc/ChartPalettes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the custom color of palette as per your requirements

The list of color palette to be separated by comma e.g:

'paletteColors' :'FF0000,0372AB,FF5904"

To know more about color of palette use the [link](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/chart-palettes)

Answer (score -1):

You can even try setting Hex code of the colors you wish to, in the "paletteColors" attribute.

The list of colors have to be separated by comma e.g:

`'paletteColors' :'FF0000,0372AB,FF5904"`

The chart will cycle through the list of specified colors and then render the data plot accordingly.

For further details, please refer to: **http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?ChartSS/Column2D.html#Anchor1**